# Conditional WHERE-clause at stored procedures

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, hana

I want to apply an additional `WHERE`-Parameter, if a specific value is given. We're currently working on SAP HANA, but we may are able to adapt strict stored-procedure programming to this platform. any help is very appreciated! So here's the Code:

```
PROCEDURE test (
   IN id integer,
   IN testVal VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '*',
   out ex_return DB-SCHEME     
)
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
--DEFAULT SCHEMA <default_schema_name>
READS SQL DATA AS
BEGIN

ex_return =
    SELECT  
        L."ID",
        LW."ID"
    FROM DB1 L
        INNER JOIN DB2 LW
            ON L."id" = LW."id"
    WHERE 
            L."id" = :id
        AND LW."testVal" LIKE :testVal       -- this one only, if :testVal != '*' 
;

END
```

What have I tried yet? I tried to `CONCAT` the `SELECT` with a calculated `WHERE` (`IF`-Conditions) an then the `EXECUTE`-Command, but it seems like SAP HANA doesn't support that. Then I tried to match the requirements with `CASE` within the `WHERE`-Clause:

```
WHERE ... CASE :wert <> '*' THEN ... END
```

Comment: Have you considered `...AND (LW."testval" LIKE :testval OR :testval = '*')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AND (LW."testVal" LIKE :testVal OR :testVal = '*')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly can't you use the APPLY_FILTER function?

```
PROCEDURE test (
   IN id integer,
   IN testVal VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '',
   out ex_return DB-SCHEME     
)
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
--DEFAULT SCHEMA <default_schema_name>
READS SQL DATA AS
BEGIN

ex_return =
    SELECT  
        L."ID",
        LW."ID"
    FROM DB1 L
        INNER JOIN DB2 LW
            ON L."id" = LW."id"
    WHERE 
            L."id" = :id;

ex_filtered = APPLY_FILTER (:ex_return, :testVal);

END;
```

In the variable testVal you now can provide the whole condition, e.g.

```
call test (1, ' "testVal" like ''%ABC%'' ');
```

All that is covered in the documentation http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/a0/9d584807f84477a64d7625ca45b089/content.htm?frameset=/en/a9/4461d71e8145a78d990deac4823858/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/ed/4f384562ce4861b48e22a8be3171e5/plain.htm&node_id=73

- Lars